# Ubuntu wont run on Windows 8.1

Tags: installation

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on windows 8.1 with no flash drive or CD and resarted my computer. when i tried to pick ubuntu as my os i shortly got a error screen saying that ubuntu is missing files and won't run. any help?

Comment: You're going to have to tell us the exact error.. Are you trying to use WUBI?

Answer (score 1):

On the Ubuntu [site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows) there is said that:

> Windows installer is not compatible with Windows 8 or UEFI firmware, and is not available for Ubuntu 13.10. Please download a 64-bit flavour of Ubuntu Desktop.
>   [Learn more](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Comment: yes but i checked 12.04 LTS and I can use Windows Installer

Comment: I don't know what do you need Ubuntu for, but you can try VirtualBox (gorąco polecam).

Comment: I want Ubuntu for personal use because i like it better than windows 8.1 but dzienki :)

Comment: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Other_installation_guides) you have everything about Ubuntu installation. On the bottom you will find instructions how to [dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Windows) Ubuntu with Windows, there about [partitioning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Partitions) etc. Miłej zabawy

Comment: @Bartek WUBI is compatible with 12.04, but not Windows 8.

Comment: Wubi does not work on gpt partitioned drives. So it can work on Windows 8 if you installed yourself in BIOS/MBR mode. But all pre-installed Windows 8 are UEFI and use gpt. Better instructions for UEFI installs http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI